# Lognormal distribution of interest rate

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have a task:

The annual rate of return in year $t$ , i.e., $(1 + i_{t})$ where $i_{0}$ represents the interest rate from $t=0$ to $t=1$, follows a log-normal distribution with an expected value of $108\%$ and a standard deviation of $20\%$ . The rates of return in subsequent years are independent of each other. What amount needs to be invested one-time at $t = 0$ so that with a $95\%$ probability, the value of the investment after 5 years is at least $500$?

I tried to calculate $P(X\cdot I^5>500)=0.95$, where $X$ is the value of investment and $I$ is random variable which describes interest rate, but I didn't get the proper answer. How this task should be solved? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are 108 and 20 supposed to be percentages? They seem pretty high for rates of return.

Comment: Can you express the fact that each $I=(1+i_t)$ is lognormal as a mathematical formula? I don't want to give you that solution but this is the key.